# Kettle Spoon - variable in file name input

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, data-integration

anyone know how to set variable for file name in 'Text File Input'?
I want the file name depends on when I execute the transformation, example:

```
D:\input_file_<variable>.txt

today = D:\input_file_20131128.txt
tomorrow = D:\input_file_20131129.txt
```

FYI, I'm using Kettle Spoon - 4.2.0

Comment: can you say what and all step you used?
i want to see your transformation.

Comment: this is the simple example. only upload text file to db. you can download at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2DhJg42FPwWS1VMaHlOc3JfajA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In set form, you can use variable as **${Variable_Name}** in file name.

You should notice the system information:

> Please remember that the variables you define with this step can't be used in this transformation. This is simply because all steps in a transformation run in parallel without a certain order of execution.
>
> As alternative correct usage, you can set variables you want  to use in the first transformation of a job

Comment: it works!! and don't forget to enable the 'Replace variable in script?'